# JQuery variable if statement error

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am trying to check whether the content that a user has submitted contains the correct information. I am doing this by adding the inputted context to a variable [code] and then trying an if else catch to see whether it matches what I want. [strong] variable.

However, it does not appear to be working, can anyone shed some light on this? Please see the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#button-bold').click(function() {  
        var code = jQuery("textarea#bold-code").val();

        var $pass = "Congratulations, You have entered this correctly";
        var $fail = "Oops, Look again, can you see where you have gone wrong?"

        var $strong = "<strong>Recreate this preview Exactly</strong>"; 

        if (code == strong) {
            alert(pass);
            $('#bold-output').append(code)

        }else {
            alert(fail);
        }
});
});
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You've got `$strong` in one place and `strong` in the other? Ditto `$pass` and `$fail`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried adding the $ to them all at first but still missed the fact that [code] didnt have one so it didnt work. Thank you again :) How do I +1 your comment?

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to upvote a comment (it wouldn't do much beyond tell other people "yeah this is a helpful comment" anyway). If @Rup posted his comment as an answer, however, you'd be able to accept that as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got mismatched variable names with and without dollars - you're defining `$strong`, `$pass` and `$fail` with leading dollars but using `strong`, `pass` and `fail` without the dollar.

(As an aside, where you see the dollar prefix on JavaScript variables it usually means that they contain jQuery selectors, e.g.

```
var $output = $('#bold-output');
```

rather than general data - but that's just one convention.)